# Is it possible to configure a format provider for the File sink using JSON configuration?

Tags: serilog

In the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/README.md) for the [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) a JSON formatter is used:

```
// Install-Package Serilog.Formatting.Compact
.WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "log.txt")
```

Is it possible to do the same using JSON configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the `Args` object, specify the full type name of the formatter:

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "log.txt",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameters to the formatter, like making a `JsonFormatter` a `RenderedJsonFormatter`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado did you find a way to pass the parameters?

Comment: Not that I can recall now.

Comment: If you're able to construct the formatter as a `public static` property on a class somewhere, you can use [the `::` property access syntax](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/test/Serilog.Settings.Configuration.Tests/StringArgumentValueTests.cs#L92) to do this.