# Serilog appsettings config with custom format provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, serilog, appsettings

I'm trying to configure Serilog in `appsettings.json`, and I have a custom format provider I want to use. I'm having issues getting Serilog to find my class.

My project is an ASP.NET Core project using .NET 7.

Originally I configured Serilog in code like this in `Program.cs`:

```
using TestProj.Formatting;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console(formatProvider: new Iso8601Formatter())
    .CreateLogger();
```

`Iso8601Formatter` is a class in `TestProj.Formatting`. Using this approach everything works fine, it compiles and output is formatted like expected.

Trying to move the config into `appsettings.json` the relevant section looks like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": ["TestProj"],
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "formatProvider": "TestProj.Formatting.Iso8601Formatter"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When trying to start up the project I get the following error:
`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Type TestProj.Formatting.Iso8601Formatter was not found.`

I've double checked that the `TestProj.dll` is copied to the output folder (`TestProj\bin\Debug\net7.0`), and it's there.
How can I get Serilog to find my custom format provider?

Comment: you need a full type name. check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943202/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-format-provider-for-the-file-sink-using-json-confi

Comment: @vhr In the `formatProvider` value I'm already specifying the full name, or am I misunderstanding something? The class is named `Iso8601Formatter` in the namespace `TestProj.Formatting`.

Comment: try  "formatProvider": "TestProj.Formatting.Iso8601Formatter, TestProj" where TestProj is the name of the assembly

Comment: @jeb Oh, that works great, thanks! So now I understood what `vhr` meant as well, I interpreted the config in the linked question like they configured two separate formatters. If any of you provide a real answer I'll accept it. Or maybe the question should be closed as a duplicate. I couldn't find the linked question when I searched initially.

Comment: @orderlyfashion, sorry for the confusion :) I thought it was straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the name of the assembly.

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": ["TestProj"],
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "formatProvider": "TestProj.Formatting.Iso8601Formatter, Testproj"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

'Testproj' is the full name of the assembly.